# Exercise on discontinuous coefficients in first order pde

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following exercise on first order pde with discontinuous coefficients, which I've found online.
It consists in giving an unambiguous meaning to the following equation $$u_t+\textrm{sign}(x)u_x=0,\,\,\,\,u(0,x)=u_0(x)$$
The hint consists in approximating the problem with the following
$$u_t+f_\epsilon(x)u_x=0$$
with $f_\epsilon (x)$ a smooth non decreasing function, such that $f_\epsilon(x)=\textrm{sign(x)}$ if $\vert x\vert>\epsilon$ and then in passing to the limit of $\epsilon\to 0$.
I've solved the regularized problem with the method of characteristics getting as characteristic curves $x(t)=t+c$ in $x>\epsilon$, $x(t)=-t+c$ in $x<-\epsilon$ and in the remaining region I draw curves in a qualitative way. But now, what about the limit? I have problems in the region $\vert x\vert<t$ in crossing the axis $x=0$. Any suggestions for the limit?

Comment: To have a limit of solutions, one needs to have solutions first. Which means you need a boundary/initial condition that would determine a solution to regularized problem uniquely.

Comment: Yes for sure; I forgot to write that I'm delaing with the initial value problem with $u(0,x)=u_0(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f_\epsilon$ to be an odd function (which is a natural thing to do) and observe that the characteristics are even as functions of $x$: that is, writing a characteristic as $t=t(x)$ gives $t(x)=t(-x)$. With the initial condition $u(0,x)=u_0(x)$,  there is no solution to regularized problem unless $u_0$ is an even function. And if $u_0$ is even, the solution satisfies $u(x,t)=u_0(|x|-t)$ for $|x|>t+\epsilon$. In the limit $\epsilon\to0$ this determines the solution to original problem for $|x|\ge t$. The region $|x|\le t$ remains undetermined; the initial value problem does not tell us  what $u$ does there.

Comment: The problem in the equation is that the coefficient is discontinuous; so you want to define the solution of the initial problem as the limit of the solution of the regularized one. But passing to the limit I'm not succeding in understanding how to proceed in the region $\vert x\vert<t$.

Comment: To have a limit of solutions, one needs to have solutions first. Which means you need a boundary/initial condition that would determine a solution to regularized problem uniquely.

Comment: @Sue I edited the answer. The solution is not determined by the initial data in the region $|x|<t$; the data simply does not propagate there. You would need a boundary condition on $u(0,t)$, $t>0$, to know what it is. As is, in this region you could have $u(x,t)=\phi(t-|x|)$ for any function $\phi:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Bare I agree with you; it's just the problem I had.